# Autoload nested folder classes in custom namespace with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

i have these directory and file structure.

i want to load my **Wtf class** in **Models** namespace.

in fact i want to add some providers to my project and want to locate them in own folder for classify them but call them with one **namespace**

its possible?

```
.
├── composer.json
├── index.php
├── src
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   └── GameController.php
│   ├── Game
│   │   └── Game.php
│   ├── Models
│   │   ├── Game.php
│   │   └── Wtf
│   │       └── Wtf.php
│   └── Player
│       └── Player.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── autoload_static.php
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        └── LICENSE
```

*Error*

```
[500]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class 'Rp76\Models\Wtf' not found in /home/reza/www/wtf/index.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/reza/www/wtf/index.php on line 13
```

*composer.json*

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Rp76\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

use Rp76\Game\Game;
use Rp76\Controllers\GameController;
use Rp76\Player\Player;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

new Game();
new Player();
new GameController();
new \Rp76\Models\Game();
new \Rp76\Models\Wtf();
```

*Wtf.php*

```
<?php

namespace Rp76\Models;

class Wtf
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Wtf<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your class is located inside a folder named `Wtf`, the correct namespace would be `namespace Rp76\Models\Wtf;` and then the reference would be `\Rp76\Models\Wtf\Wtf();`. This is how the psr-4 autoloading works, each folder under the root (your `src`-folder) will be part of the namespace space.

Comment: @M.Eriksson i know that, but i need do that!
i think that's possible

Comment: Move php file under folder src/Rp76

Comment: It's not possible if you want to follow the standard and not make it confusing for others (or even yourself when you come back to the code after a while). Why do you "need" that? Why can't you just add `\Wtf` to the namespace or put the `Wtf.php` directly inside the `Models` folder? If you, for what ever reason, need to do this, you could try to just add another line in your psr-4 section in your composer file: `"Rp76\Models\\": "src/Models/Wtf/"`. Not sure if this will allow both `Models/` and `Models/Wtf/`.

Comment: @M.Eriksson i want to add several class for my providers and want to call them dynamical in programing way.

someting like this: 

`$a=$_POST['provider'];new $a();`

Comment: That is a terrible idea! That would basically allow anyone to instantiate what ever class they want on your server! Either way, that doesn't answer any of my questions why that would mean you "need" to have the same namespace for multiple folders. Why can't `provider` contain the extra `Wtf`? At the end of the day, you will need to validate the `provider` value before you just use it (or you've just created a massive security issue). In that step, you can simply see if it is `Wtf` and then add the extra `Wtf` in the namespace?

Comment: @M.Eriksson i have a class that decide which provider can process incoming request.
now how call my providers?